# Generate Google +1 badge dynamically via javascript

Tags: jquery

I need to generate div via jquery append method and then add google +1 badge with number of likes to this div. In every source I found, this div is already generated in html, but I need generate it dynamically via jquery.

I tried this code(liveReady is jquery plugin which combines document ready method with jquery.live method and .g-plusone is div, which is created via jquery append.). But function $.getScript ends with error(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect' of undefined )

```
$('#lbExif').append('<div class="g-plusone"></div>');    
$.liveReady('.g-plusone',function addG(){
        $(".g-plusone").html("<g:plusone width=\"55\" height=\"20\" href=\"http://blog.2k1y.com\"></g:plusone>");
        $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js");
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will generate the button dynamically using javascript asynchronously without waiting for the page to finish loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript';
    po.async = true;

    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Just execute it whenever you want using the library of your choice (ie: jQuery)

If you would like to set script tag parameters, use the following syntax:

```
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'zh-CN',
    parsetags: 'onload'
  };
```

A full example is included in the following URL:

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#example-async-load

Comment: But in your case, there is already <g:plusone></g:plusone> in html code. In my case, I need to add <g:plusone></g:plusone> via jquery.append. I tried your way, but in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to add <g:plusone></g:plusone> before executing the function above. i would give it a name and execute it after the append.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but it still doesn't work, no error nothing, it seems like this function isn't performed, but according to Firebug debugger, everything seems to work fine. Could you please make working example? I really don't know where could be error.

Comment: Hi, it finally works, I had forgot, that I called plusone.js script already in head. After I deleted it from head, it works like charm.